# Excel count target then output value in cell

Tags: vba, excel, count

I have a workbook with three sheets (Dash, HT, RV.)

I am trying to write a macro/function that counts how many times a value from 'Dash' exists in a specific column within sheet 'RV' then output that value in a specific cell within 'Dash'

I could go so far as to say that the value within 'Dash' is static and repeat it (The variable from 'Dash' won't ever change as it's a list of Usernames)

In my head it's something like: Count whatever.variable.Dash in column J of sheet.RV print in Dash.B2...

I was able to find a MsgBox option that works, but I have to manually type in each Username (which is a 16character name (string)) then a MsgBox tells me the occurrences. I'm looking to just automate this option with a fixed/static username in the macro/function because the amount of rows in 'RV' can vary between 700 entries to 23k entries

The MsgBox option is:

```
Dim Count as Integer
Dim Target As String
Dim Cell as Object
Dim N As Integer

Sub Target_Count()
    Count = 0
    Target = InputBox("character(s) to find?")
    If Target = "" Then GoTo Done
        For Each Cell in Selection
            N = InStr(1, cell.Value, target)
            While N <> 0
                Count = count + 1
                N = InStr(n + 1, cell.Value, target)
            Wend
        Next Cell
    MsgBox count & " Occurrences of " & target
Done:
End Sub
```

I want the input box target to be 'Dash.A1:8' and the occurrences to be printed in 'Dash.B1:8'

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a `countif()` formula rather than programming a macro?  say the column you were counting the "dash"'s in was column B in sheet RV,  Then in the cell in sheet Dash, the formula would be:

`=COUNTIF(RV!B:B,"dash")`

[image][image]

Or, if you wanted to vary what you were counting, you simply replace the hardcoded "dash" in the formula with the input cell address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want VBA you can use this. Adjust it however you want.

```
Sub Target_Count_2()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Count As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = wb.Worksheets("RV").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Dim strArr() As Variant
strArr() = wb.Worksheets("RV").Range("J1:J" & LastRow).Value
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String

    For Each Cell In wb.Worksheets("Dash").Range("B1:B8")
        Count = 0
        str = Cell.Offset(, -1).Value2
        For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
            If str = strArr(i, 1) Then Count = Count + 1
            'If InStr(strArr(i, 1), str) > 0 Then Count = Count + 1
        Next
        Cell.Value2 = Count
    Next

Set Cell = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that `str = strArr(i, 1)` will match only full value in cells, while `InStr(strArr(i, 1), str) > 0` will also match parts in cells. Let's say you are looking for `"AAA"` in cell with the value `"AAAB"`. The first method will not add additional `1` to the `Count`, while the second method will.